# How can I convert a varchar column in SQL into different columns?

Tags: sql, varchar, calculated-columns

I have a table with a `Scores` column, it looks like:

```
user_id | scores        
1       |--- - 18
2       |--- - 60 - 26 - 6
3       |--- - 18 - 43 - 23 - 23
4       |--- - 60 - 26 - 6
```

The scores has at most 4 parts, like the user with `user_id`: 3, and may have less than 4 parts.

So what I want is that for each user, a new table should look like:

```
user_id | part1 | part2 | part3 | part4     
1       | 18    | NULL  | NULL  | NULL 
2       | 60    | 26    | 6     | NULL
3       | 60    | 60    | 23    | 23
4       | 60    | 26    | 6     | NULL
```

Thanks very much

Comment: This is going to be difficult to handle using SQL.  Is there any chance you can clean up the data before bringing it into your database?

Comment: Your data is not normalized..but maybe normalizing them is just the goal of your question.. Anyway, you should make a small program which does this, more than a query

Comment: Whenever you ask about `sql` you should tag your question with the actual RDBMS (incl. version). The answer is highly depending on this information!